# Why is cold water coming from the hot part of the faucet?

Tags: plumbing, water

The last plumber I called made a test.  He closed the cold water intake to the 40 gallon gas water heater.  The he opened all the hot water faucets in my house. After a minute passed,
the faucets, instead of hot water were pouring abundantly cold water.  He said this was weird, and he said it may be the washing machine. I did not understand.

Please explain why cold water was coming out of the hot water faucets.

Comment: Mike - please register your account, then you can request that all the other accounts you've created can be merged into one. Follow the instructions on this page - http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Comment: @ChrisF at least one of his accounts is registered, but since he isn't responding to requests, I'm just going to start deleting the dup questions/answers/etc: http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/11713/mike

Comment: @BMitch - I must have missed that one. Deletion seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

When he closed the valve on the heater cold water inlet, the pressure should have dropped off and the water ceased to flow. The hot water circuit is supposed to be fed from the cold water circuit only through the shutoff valve on the water heater.

Continued flow of water in the system indicates there is a cross-connect somewhere in the system between the hot water circuit and the cold water circuit.

Usually this happens where you have one of those instant hot water circulator pumps. They monitor the temperature in the hot circuit at the remote location where you want quicker delivery of hot water and push the cool water from the hot circuit into the cold circuit till the hot water circuit reaches a set temperature. If the pressure in the hot water circuit drops, there should be a check valve that prevents cold water from pushing back through the hot water circuit.

Another potential cross-connect is where you have a shower with a balance valve. It works by first turning the cold water on full and then slowly turning on the hot water. If the plumber had the shower turned on as one of the hot water faucets, it could backfeed cold water into the hot water system as there's no pressure in the hot water system to prevent it.

The solenoid valves on the washing machine could also do this under rather odd circumstances, the easiest way of eliminating that is to just operate the water cutoff valve. In modern installations it's a dual ball, single lever valve that shuts both hot and cold off to the washing machine.

All other cross connect type water flow would require faucets to have both hot and cold water on simultaneously, feeding back some cold water into the unpressurized hot circuit, which if he only ran hot water through them, wouldn't occur.

The final issue is a plumbing misconfiguration somewhere, you probably would have already noticed that.

Comment: I'm running into this same problem. I disconnect the water heater and both connections have pressurized cold water. I turned everything off and it's the same. All the pipes are behind concrete walls. Is there a trick to figuring out where a crossover might be? No recirculator, and the washing machine is disconnected. Could it just be a broken shower knob that's letting water pass through while the shower is not on?